# Why does 'jamais' seem to have the opposite of its normal meaning in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulaire

This sentence from Proust:

> Ou bien en dormant j’avais rejoint sans effort un âge à jamais révolu de ma vie
> primitive.

was translated by D.J. Enright as:

> Or else while sleeping I had drifted back to an earlier stage in my life, now for ever outgrown

Since 'revolu' is defined in LaRousse as

> Être écoulé, complètement achevé

An in Cambridge as

> qui appartient au passé et n’existe plus | past |  au moins dix-huit ans | at least eighteen

I would think the correct translation would be:

> Or else while sleeping I had drifted back to an earlier stage in my life, never outgrown

I realize 'jamais' does sometime mean 'ever' but I don't understand how I am supposed to distinguish the two meanings. Suppose I wanted to express that I had never outgrown my childhood, how would I do it.

Answer (score 2):

1. *I realize 'jamais' does sometime mean 'ever' but I don't understand how I am supposed to distinguish the two meanings.*

   There is no ambiguity in this sentence because ***jamais*** follows ***à*** which makes the set expression ***à jamais***: *pour toujours* (forever):

   [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jamais) (emphasis mine)

   > **JAMAIS**, adv.
   > I. − [*Jamais* n'est pas en corrélation avec une particule négative] À un moment quelconque, à quelque moment que ce soit.
   > [...]
   > I. − [Dans un syntagme prépositionnel]
   >
   > 1. ***À (tout) jamais***. Dans tout le temps à venir sans qu'il y ait interruption ou fin. **Synonyme *pour toujours***. *La mort les a réunis à jamais. Je serai à vous à tout jamais* (Académie 1878-1935). *Les lois de Kepler ont **à jamais** détruit la simplicité de la doctrine astronomique des Anciens* (Renouvier, Essais crit. gén., 3e essai, 1864, p. 89). *Un matin d'octobre, mes diplômes celés à tout jamais au fond d'une malle, je pris le tablier bleu et le balai* (Frapié, Maternelle, 1904, p. 6):
   > 2. Depuis, j'ai eu le temps d'assembler les cartes, les compas, et de fixer ***à** tout **jamais*** l'endroit où, pour la première fois, j'ai compris la beauté des yeux de Tanit-Zerga. Benoit, *Atlant.*,1919, p. 298.

2. *Suppose I wanted to express that I had never outgrown my childhood, how would I do it?*

Just use *jamais*:

> *Je n'ai jamais dépassé le stade de l'enfance.*
> *Je ne suis jamais sorti de l'enfance.*

Comment: cool, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "*à jamais*" is an expression that means "forever", but it follows the generic rule so I'll also explain it.

It's a little tricky because  what you should do in correct French and what is found in speech is quite different.

In literature, there should **always be a negation** (usually "*ne*") for *jamais* when it means "never" (never comes from "not ever" in English too). The only exception is when it's used as an answer.

> Il **n'**est jamais venu. (*He never came.*)

> Il est revenu, plus fort que jamais. (*He came back, stronger than ever*)

> Jamais ! (*Never!*)

And in speech, we very often drop the *ne*, but *jamais* is **almost never used to mean "ever"**.

> Il vient jamais à l'entraînement. (*He never comes to practice*)

The only construction using it that is rather common is:

> C'est le pire film que j'ai jamais vu. (*It's the worst movie I've ever seen.*)

Here there is no confusion because it's clear it can only mean "ever". In almost all other sentences in which English uses "ever", we use a different word in French, so it rarely causes a problem.